# What are possible targets with OpenACC?

Tags: nvidia, openacc, pgi-accelerator

I am willing to use OpenACC on some projects. I am not sure of the possible architectures.

Officially, with PGI compiler, **the accelerator can be a multicore CPU or a Nvidia Tesla GPU**. 
**Are there any other possible target ?** (eventually using other compiler)

I red somewhere that pgcc used to be compatible with Radeon GPU.
I saw a project using an Nvidia Quadro. Are Nvidia Geforce also compatible ?

Answer (score 0):

I remember that OpenACC is also supported on Radeon GPU but not very well and I didn't try that GPU, one reason is that in recent years NVIDIA bought PGI company, so PGI complier support NVIDIA GPU very well,

For second question: every NVIDIA GPU has a computation ability such as 2.1 or 3.5, and the higher the better, I have a old laptop(I bought it 5 years ago) with a NVIDIA GT630M with computation ability 2.1 (nearly the lowest computation ability), it can also use PGI complier, I think it belongs to Geforce family

And you can find more information from OpenACC official website, and Nvidia website to confirm whether your GPU is supported

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I asked it here because i didn't find something convenient on their website